# how to use like query to search a column value with % in it?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
tablename - names
values    - %dfdf
            hhhh
            %fgfg
```

Now if i want to get all the names `starting from %`, how to do it ?

Comment: I dont have a sql server installed on this machine will try it later. But like("\%%"); will work.. @ below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) to test if a value starts with a certain substring. Since `%` is a special character it must be escaped.

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character. If you do not specify the ESCAPE character, “\” is assumed.

Try this:

```
SELECT `values`
FROM names
WHERE `values` LIKE '\%%'
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69c51/3)